# Chardin.js - Creating a toggle button

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I create a toggle button for Chardin.js? [Chardin Website](http://heelhook.github.io/chardin.js/)

I know the script is all linked up correctly as when I run the script below it shows fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').chardinJs('start');
});
```

However, I'm wanting the user to click a button to show the information, not on document load.

I have tried:

```
<script>$('.button').on('click', function(){
$('body').chardinJs('start')
});</script>
```

with this:

`<span class="button"><a href="#" class="btn btn-large primary" data-toggle="chardinjs" data-intro="This button toggles the overlay, you can click it, even when the overlay is visible" data-position="left">Show Me</a></span>`

I fear I'm barking up the wrong tree, can anyone please advise?
Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('#some-button').on('click', function() { $('.container').chardinJs('start') });
```

you can find more here: http://www.codersgrid.com/2013/07/03/chardin-js-make-overlay-instructions-easily/

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically ask for toggle, chardinJs happens to have such instruction.

HTML (featuring bootstrap classes too with the button):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/CSS/chardinjs.css" />
...
<button id="toggleHelp" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>Help</button>
...
<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/chardin.js'></script>
```

And then js:

```
// 1. Just initializing
$(document).ready(function(){ $('body').chardinJs(); });

// 2. Later somewhere still during ready bind the event handler
$('#toggleHelp').on('click', function() { $('body').chardinJs('toggle') });
```

That's all.

Comment: Plus here is a Chardin.js demo site which actually works in a desktop browser: https://mrcsabatoth.github.io/chardin.js/